# Check file size and if file is not growing, then move it [readdir]

Tags: perl

I made script first for Windows platform and it worked. Now I have moved the script to Ubuntu and can not get it working.

Is the problem in reading the filesize?

```
while ( opendir my $dirh, "/share/Dropbox/test/in" ) {

    while ( my $file = readdir $dirh ) {

        # filter . & .. folders out
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);

        my $size1 = -s $file;
        print "$size1\n";

        sleep 2;

        my $size2 = -s $file;
        print "$size2\n";

        if ( $size1 == $size2 ) {
            move( $file, "/share/Dropbox/test/out" );
        }
    }

    sleep 1;
}
closedir DIR;
```

And the warnings I get when running this:

> Use of uninitialized value $size1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./file_ready_2.pl line 20.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $size2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./file_ready_2.pl line 23.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $size2 in numeric eq (==) at ./file_ready_2.pl line 25.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $size1 in numeric eq (==) at ./file_ready_2.pl line 25.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $size1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./file_ready_2.pl line 20.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $size2 in concatenation (.) or string at ./file_ready_2.pl line 23.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the one
[described by @AnFi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579032/622310).
This works for me on Linux (just comment out the `move` line):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirpath = shift;    # first cmdline argument

opendir my $dirh, $dirpath
  or die "Can't opendir $dirpath: $!\n";

chdir $dirpath
  or die "Can't chdir to $dirpath: $!\n";

while ( my $file = readdir $dirh ) {

    next if $file =~ m/^\./;    # skip dotfiles
    next if not -f $file;       # skip non-files

    my $size1 = -s $file;
    print "$size1\n";
    sleep 2;
    my $size2 = -s $file;
    print "$size2\n";

    if ( $size1 == $size2 ) {

        print "moving $file\n";
        #move($file,"/share/Dropbox/test/out");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The filename returned by `readdir` is relative to the `opendir` directory.  Files test (e.g. `-s`) will not work (or test wrong file) if you execute the script with another directory as current directory.

`perldoc -f readdir`

> **readdir DIRHANDLE**
>   [...] If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a
>   "readdir", you'd better prepend the directory in question.
>   Otherwise, because we didn't "chdir" there, it would have bee
>   testing the wrong file. [...]

```
# FIX1 Keep directory name in variable, make it end with directory separator 
my $dir = "/share/Dropbox/test/in/";
while (opendir my $dirh, $dir ) {
    ...
    # FIX2: prepend directory name (with trailing directory separator)
    #       for size tests  
    my $size1 = -s "$dir$file";
    print "$size1\n";
    sleep 2;
    my $size2 = -s "$dir$file";
    print "$size2\n";
    ....
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. Actually this script worked perfectly in Windows platform.  
Can you please provide solution for this or point what library I should use ?

Comment: Sample fixes added to the reply.

Comment: You should ordinarily put a path separator `/` between the directory and the filename. There is no guarantee that the directory name will end with a slash, but multiple consecutive slashes will be collapsed into one.

Comment: I have made the recommendation (end directory name with directory separator) to make the script portable between systems with different directory separators.

Comment: Rather than making a procedural rule, you should `use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile'` and `$file = catfile($dir, $file)` which is portable across systems. As I said, it will all work anyway as long as you use `"$dir/$file"` as multiple consecutive slashes will be collapsed to one.

Comment: You are are right **for bigger scripts**.  I use frequently scripts with less than fifty lines. I makes me avoid using external modules for "trivial" tasks. One size does not fit all ;-)

Comment: @Anfi: Then, like I said, just use `"$dir/$file"`. It will always work whether there's a slash at the end of the directory path or not.